# Low and muffled audio from two different MSI motherboards

Tags: audio, drivers, motherboard

I own an [MSI z390 gaming plus](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/support/MPG-Z390-GAMING-PLUS) ([HW manual](https://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/mb/E7B51v11.pdf)) and an [MSI B75A-G43](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B75A-G43) ([HW Manual](https://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/E7758v2.0.zip)) with the current BIOS which I run under Windows 7 and Windows 10.

I have the same problem with on-board audio on both motherboards. The audio is low and muffled.

Here what I have already tried:

- uninstall/install current Realtek driver from the MSI support pages
- disable audio enhancement
- activate sound loudness equalization
- make a clear W10 installation
- disconnect the JAUD1 front port audio cable (to check for interference it might pick up)
- start the pc with no case/Video card (to check for interference it might pick up)

I only use headsets (asus orion, audio technica mx40, cooler master mh751). Those headsets tested on my phone have good audio quality.

I also tried to use audio cards (Asus Xonar DG, Creative Sound Blaster Audigy FX) but the audio from those has static, noise, and also sounds terrible.

I have no idea how to bring back good audio. How may I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you accidentally plugged something in to the audio outputs? For example a line level signal, headphone splitter, or particularly low-impedance headphones. This sounds like the hardware may be damaged, especially as you're reporting the same issue on both boards (and other issues with other hardware).

Comment: @K7AAY 1) the OS are windows 7 and windows 10 2) i have checked the BIOS date is ok 3) i intalled the last driver from msi page

Comment: @Attie i only use these headset, i do not own other audio device, my MSI B75A-G43 worked fine until last summer but the sound suddently became bad,i only used my asus orion with this mobo

Comment: @K7AAY i contacted msi support they just they "maybe your motherboard dommaged see if you can have a other board were you bought it"

Comment: Power surges _can_ damage motherboards, and the damage can be cumulative; a lot of little sparks or overvoltages can equal one big zap. I'm not saying that's the cause, but with two different motherboards failing on two different OS which have been reinstalled, it's starting to look likely.

Comment: @K7AAY my MSI z390 gaming plus sound was bad from the start i use a 500w(new) and 450w power supply

Comment: @K7AAY the front panel jack (HDaudio)

Comment: @K7AAY i trought that too so i taked out my mobo only using my case to start the pc there were just little improvement but the audio sound stage stayed the same

Comment: @K7AAY all thing i have done is listed, i will update future test

Comment: Given what you have tested so far, I'm starting to think it may be your headphones or cable or something, and not actually your motherboards.

Comment: @LPChip mx40, MH751 are new and work fine on other device